# Initializing repository from an existing one

Tags: git

I want to start a project from an existing repository. But I don't care about it's commit history. I don't want to `git log` and see a big wall of commits. I want to clone an existing repository and then create a new repository for my project.

Is it ok to just delete the .git folder and use `git init`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting the .git, you can try:

```
git checkout --orphan <branch_name>
git add -A                           // Add all files 
git commit
git branch -D master                 // Deletes the master branch
git branch -m master                 // Rename the current branch to master
git remote set-url origin <URL>      // Set the remote URL to new repo before pushing
```

This helps you to preserve the `submodules`.

Comment: how did you guess that I needed to preserve submodules? :)

Comment: :) Its one of the things which gets messed up with .git delete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok to do so. Doing  `cd project && rm -rf .git && git init && git add . && git commit -m "fresh initialization"` will do it for you.

But in case the repo in question already has some git hooks in `.git/hooks/`, or there are some ignore rules in `.git/info/exclude`, or some special configs in `.git/config`, don't forget to create a copy of the same if you need them later.